How to render dspsinewave from https://github.com/tgroche/tikz-dsp
I'm trying to render a sine wave node using: https://github.com/tgroche/tikz-dsp without any luck.
I've used the example from https://texample.net//tikz/examples/fir-filter/ on which the code at https://github.com/tgroche/tikz-dsp is based and substituted a node from [coordinate] to [dspsinewave] but it does not render.
Are there examples for the github repository code?
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Place nodes using a matrix
    \matrix (m1) [row sep=2.5mm, column sep=5mm]
    {
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------
        \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=above] (m00) {$\theta[\eta]$};    &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m01) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m02) {};          &
        \node[dspmixer, dsp/label=above]   (m03) {PD};        &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m04) {};          &
        \node[dspsquare]                   (m05) {$\z^{-1}$}; &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m06) {};          &
        \node[dspsquare]                   (m07) {$\z^{-1}$}; &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m08) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m09) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m0X) {};          \\
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------
        \node[coordinate]                  (m10) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m11) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m12) {$h[0]$};    &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m13) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m14) {$h[1]$};    &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m15) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m16) {$h[2]$};    &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m17) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m18) {$h[3]$};    &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m19) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m1X) {};          \\
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------
        \\
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------
        \node[coordinate]                  (m20) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m21) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m22) {};          &
        \node[dspsinewave]                 (m23) {};          &
        \node[dspadder]                    (m24) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m25) {};          &
        \node[dspadder]                    (m26) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m27) {};          &
        \node[dspadder]                    (m28) {};          &
        \node[coordinate]                  (m29) {};          &
        \node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=above] (m2X) {$y[n]$};    \\
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    };
% Draw connections
    
    \begin{scope}[start chain]
        \chainin (m00);
        \chainin (m03) [join=by dspflow];
        \chainin (m12) [join=by dspconn];
        \chainin (m22) [join=by dspline];
    \end{scope}
    \draw[dspflow] (m28) -- (m2X);

\end{tikzpicture}

No error is produced.  Silent failure.

Welcome! Please post the actual code you tried to compile here and also copy-paste the error you got when you tried to compile. (I assume you got an error since you say it didn't render. If not, explain what is wrong.)

The linked example compiles fine for me, so either you didn't install the library where TeX can find it or the problem lies in code you've not shared. I am not sure which repo you're referring to. The library for the example can be downloaded from the page you linked. You don't need anything else (except TikZ etc., obviously.)

The linked example is fine.  The code from the github repository supposedly extends this library and I see some definition of dspsinwave in the code but don't know enough latex to work through and debug.

You need to provide a complete example we can compile to reproduce the error. If you are using a different library, why did you link only to the one you aren't using?

Oh, you put it in your tilte. Please put it in the body of your question.

I would stick to the 'unenhanced' version, I think. :w
